# Создание двух таблиц с неповторяющимися между собой id primary_key в DJANGO ORM

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-orm, django-model

Необходимо создать две таблицы у которых не будут совпадать id в поле primary_key. Например, в таблицу1 мы добавляем новый элемент у которого id будет = 1. Затем в таблицу2 добавляем элемент у которго id будет продолженим последовательности и равен 2. Прочитал, что для этого в SQL есть объект CREATE SEQUENCE, но я не нашёл как можно применить его в Django ORM. Есть ли возможность осущитвить подобную механику в Django?

Comment: Какая СУБД (в том числе - точная версия) используется?

Comment: на данный момент sqlite3, в будущем планируется postgresql

Comment: SQLite не поддерживает SEQUENCE (то есть оно внутри-то существует, см. https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#seqtab, но не достучаться, и "перекрёстного опыления" не допускается). PostgreSQL - поддерживает, но только для одной таблицы (OWNED BY).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил свою задачу с помощью библиотеки [django-sequences](https://pypi.org/project/django-sequences/). Она создаёт ещё одну таблицу в БД, в которой будут хранится последовательности. Удобно, что каждой последовательности можно дать своё имя и с помощью метода `get_next_value("test_sequences")` получать следующее значение последовательности.
В описании моделей, я добавил свои поля primary_key и перед сохранением нового объекта в таблицу необходимо присвоить значение последовательности к полю с primary_key.

Answer (score 2):

Обычно когда требуется решить такую задачу - общий автоинкремент,- то используется схема с дополнительной таблицей и триггерная логика.

Вот пример реализации подобной логики в MySQL: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=33446b5d68bb2cd7434c8a8983c11fac). В других СУБД оно реализуется аналогично.

Как отобразить это на Django - вот даже не спрашивайте...

---

Ну и в принципе неплохим решением может быть разделение значений генерируемых уникальных ключей. Если СУБД поддерживает не-единичный seed, то одна таблица настраивается на генерирование чётных id, другая соответственно на нечётные. Если же не поддерживает, то весь диапазон значений для типа данных делится пополам (или в некоей пропорции, если прогнозируемое количество записей в таблицах серьёзно различается), и одна начинает генерацию с единицы, а другая с рассчитанного значения. Правда, в обоих случаях никакой последовательности значений во времени даже не прогнозируется.

Answer (score 1):

Есть пара вариантов

1. Унаследовать 2 эти модели от общей НЕ АБСТРАТНОЙ модели. В итоге это будут 3 таблицы, Они будут ссылаться на объекты основной модели, и эти ключи будут уникальными (не сам id)
2. Использовать GUID. В Django есть UUIDField, для ключа можно использовать его, вероятность что ключи совпадут мала.

Других вариантов предложить пока что не могу

---

```py
import uuid
from django.db import models

class MyUUIDModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936182/using-a-uuid-as-a-primary-key-in-django-models-generic-relations-impact)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. К сожеленю, первый вариант мне не подходит, так как есть необходимость именно в уникальности чисел между двумя таблицами. Попробую найти информацию про GuidField.

Comment: уточнил информацию для вас

Comment: в первом варианте в каждой тайблице у вас будет по 2 ключа, 1 локальный для таблицы, второй относится к базовой модели, вот он будет уникальным для 2х производных моделей